# How to select one record at time between two dates

Tags: php, mysql

I've a table that stores the reservations of rooms and for each room I want select the reservations, by a PHP date. Here is it the query:

```
SELECT id_prenotazione, id_alloggio, FROM_UNIXTIME(data_checkin,'%d/%m/%Y') AS checkin,
  FROM_UNIXTIME(data_checkout,'%d/%m/%Y') AS checkout, pagata, esclusiva
FROM prenotazioni 
WHERE id_alloggio = $id_alloggio
  AND FROM_UNIXTIME(data_checkin,'%d/%m/%Y') >= ".$data."
  OR FROM_UNIXTIME(data_checkout,'%d/%m/%Y') <= " .$data.") 
ORDER BY checkin ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

but if there are two or more reservations on the same room, the query always returns the first reservation, while if I change "ASC" with "DESC", returns only the last reservation. I want the single reservation of a specific room ($id_allogio) in a specific date($data). What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: very hard to understand your language   :)

Comment: By providing a format argument to `FROM_UNIXTIME()` you are obtaining a string result against which your comparison operations will be performed under a lexicographic ordering.  What format is `$data`?

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: Do you want the reservation whose checkin date is before $data, and checkout date is after it? Because you've got an OR clause there, not AND. Confused as to what you're actually trying to get

Comment: First of all, sorry for my english.
$data came from this:

$date = strtotime($current_year."-".$current_month."-".$current_day);          
$date = date("d/m/Y",$date);

FROM_UNIXTIME return a string? I don't know this.

Comment: I try to clarify ideas. :)
I want the single reservation of a room when $data is between checkin and checkout date.
Here is it the SQLFiddle link:

[link]http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e621f7/5

Comment: If changing your order clause changes the reservation you are getting back, then you can not get "the single reservation" of the room, because there is more than 1 (given your where clause)! I would remove the order & limit clause and change your OR to an AND, does that give you what you want?

Comment: I changed the format of the dates in the database to unify and simplify all the controls. Now the query works correctly and returning the record of the single reservation.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the between statement :

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,blabla 
FROM prenotazioni 
WHERE 
id_alloggio = $id_alloggio 
and FROM_UNIXTIME(data_checkin,'%d/%m/%Y') between date_1 AND date_2
ORDER BY checkin ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I try to use BETWEEN statement but I don't have two different date (date_1 and date_2); I have one date ($data) that should be between checkin and checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Your question makes it difficult to tell exactly what you need.  It seems that you need to see the single reservation matching a particular room on a particular day.

But you don't tell us what should happen if there are multiple reservations for a room on a day. That is, you don't tell us what should happen if there is an overbooking.

At any rate, your scheme for handling your `TIMESTAMP` (that is, your UNIXTIME) data items is not very good.

I suggest you revise your query as follows:

```
SELECT id_prenotazione,
       id_alloggio,
       FROM_UNIXTIME(data_checkin,'%d/%m/%Y') AS checkin,    
       FROM_UNIXTIME(data_checkout,'%d/%m/%Y') AS checkout, 
       pagata, 
       esclusiva
  FROM prenotazioni 
 WHERE id_alloggio = $id_alloggio 
   AND STR_TO_DATE($data, '%d/%m/%Y') >= data_checkin
   AND STR_TO_DATE($data, '%d/%m/%Y') <  data_checkout + INTERVAL 1 DAY
 ORDER BY checkin ASC
```

What did I change here?

First, I converted your presentation style date, which represents 17-Dec-2013 as 17/12/2013, to an internal MySQL native date format, *before* using it for comparison using inequalities like `>=` and `<`. It's necessary to do that.  When you compare strings like `17/12/2013` and `18/11/2013` you get incorrect ordering.

Additionally, the way I wrote the query allows MySQL to use indexes to satisfy it.

Second, I changed your checkout comparison to

```
   parameter-date < data_checkout + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

That's because you seem to be using data types for `data_checkin` and `data_checkout` that include both calendar dates and times. The comparison I used allows the result to be correct when `data_checkout` shows a checkout time other than midnight.

Finally, I got rid of the LIMIT 1. It seems to me that you need to know if there's more than one reservation for a room on a particular date.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive reply. 
I need to show one reservation at time for each room and handling the case when checkin and checkout are in the same date.
data_checkin and data_checkout are stored in PHP TIMESTAMP while $data is in PHP date format.

Comment: Interesting. So I can make a reservation both to check in and to check out on Saturday, March 8th?  Does that make sense? Or will I check in on March 8th and check out on March 9th?  It is hard to give precise query code without understanding your business rules.

Comment: For example: one reservation has checkin date on March 8th and checkout date on March 9th. Another reservation, on the same room, has checkin date on March 9th and checkout date on March 12th.

Comment: So, if I query about March 9, which reservation should I see? I guess the second one. Therefore, remove the `+ INTERVAL 1 DAY` from the query in my answer.

Comment: I try to execute the query and I get two reservations: the first with check-out date on 9th March and the second with check-in date on 9th March.
Therefore if I remove `code`+ INTERVAL 1 DAY, the query doesn't select the checkout date.

Comment: With respect, your requirements are contradictory. You cannot select just one reservation, and at the same time select all reservations from check-in date to check-out date inclusive. You either must select multiple reservations, or select reservations matching the day of check-in to the day before the day of check-out.  If you don't know what to do here, I suppose you should ask your user.

Comment: Excuse me but, one of the rules of my client is that the room must be left after 10 AM on the date of checkout, so the room is free, on the same date for a new reservation from 11 AM. Therefore, It is possible that, at the same date, the room has checked out of the previous booking and check-in of the next.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem this way:

1. I changed the format of the dates of check-in and check-out from PHP TIMESTAMP to MYSQL DATE
2. I rewrote the query on the information you have given me:

   SELECT id_prenotazione,id_alloggio, data_checkin, data_checkout, pagata, esclusiva 
   FROM prenotazioni 
   WHERE id_alloggio = $id_alloggio AND '$data' >= data_checkin AND '$data' < data_checkout + INTERVAL 1 DAY

With these corrections, the query rertuns the single reservation of specific room in a specific date.
Thanks for Your useful answer!